# ZFS RAIDZ Pool appears empty after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, home-directory, zfs

I upgraded my Ubuntu workstation where I had my home directory linked to a ZFS filesystem.

After the upgrade, I can no longer log into the desktop, but I can log in via terminal.

When I browse to the zpool mount, I get nothing in the directory listing (it appears empty).  When I do a status of the pool, it shows that everything is 100% fine and dandy.

I tried doing an export and import to see if it may help, but to no avail.

The *real kicker* though, is that I can change into directories on the mounted RAID and see files (ie, cd /mnt/RAIDSTORAGE/home/steve or cd /home/steve --> /mnt/RAIDSTORAGE/home/steve).

Any idea what I should be doing?  either the ZFS isn't booting fast enough, or in the right order, or maybe modules were swapped out?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I figured out the a fix...

It seems whatever is mounting the zfs filesystems isn't kicking off as we would normally expect.

I did the following steps to finally resolve the issue

```
sudo zpool export RAIDSTORAGE  ## use your pool name here  
sudo zfs mount -a
```

If it's not mounted then, you can try doing the following again.

```
sudo zpool import RAIDSTORAGE ## use your pool name here
```

If you reboot and find that you're still not getting your zfs mounts back, I'd try the following...

```
sudo apt-get install zfs-mountall
```

which downgraded a package to zfs-mountall from mountall, but for me, the filesystem seems to be coming back up on reboots now.

Comment: Unfortunately gives me `E: Unable to locate package zfs-mountall`